# Sub sub-menu doesn't behave as it should

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm having a problem with one of the sub-menus I've been experimenting on. The sub sub-menu for Partial doesn't behave like it should. This is a back-up navbar for our company website just in case the other isn't approved. I've used different codes for both and the other is working fine so no problem there.

I want the sub-menu for Partial to curtain to the right instead of below it.

This new one is a combination of codes I found.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/shamrocksdee/20rgfom5/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="">ABOUT <span class="arrow">&#9660;</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">M - V - V</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CHOOSE US</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">PROGRAMS</a></li>
            <li><a class="current-item" href="">EVENTS <span class="arrow">&#9660;</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="">SCHEDULE</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">CLIENTS <span class="arrow">&#9660;</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a>PARTIAL LIST <span class="arrow">&#9658;</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="">PUBLIC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">IN-HOUSE</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                        <li><a href="">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="" rel="ddsubmenu3">SOCIAL</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background:#ffffff /*url('body-bg.jpg')*/;
}

container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
}


.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:"";
}

// Menu Outline
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
    width:1400px;
    margin-left:2.2%;
    margin-top:3.6%;
    height:78px; 
    float:left; 
    padding-left:5px; 
    padding-top:5px; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
    z-index:100;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Raleway';
    font-weight:bold !important;}
    .menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#919191;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#d3d3d3;
    display: block;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

// Top Level
.menu > ul > li {
    float:center;
    display:inline-table;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-table;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#2e2728;
}

// Bottom Level
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
    float: none; 
}

.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#3e3436;
}

.sub-menu ul {
    width:160%;
    position: absolute;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    display:none; /* hides sublists */
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
    float: none;
}

// hides sub-sublists
.sub-menu li:hover ul ul {
    display:none;
} 

// shows sublist on hover
    .sub-menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
} 

.sub-menu li ul li:hover ul {
    font-size:16px;
    display: block; /* shows sub-sublist on hover */
    position: inherit;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Thanks. I'm not used to CSS codes...I'm Jurassic when it comes to CSS lol.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. "doesn't behave as it should" is not a very descriptive explanation of what is going on. Can you please tell us what you expect to see, and what you see instead the jsfiddle is great - thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. In the Client menu is the Partial sub-menu then there is a sub-menu to it. I want it to be on the right side instead of below the sub-menu itself. Like it curtains to the right, where the arrow is pointed. :)

Comment: Looking now... probably unrelated, but have you noticed that you haven't properly closed the spans? `<span class="arrow">&#9660;</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess these are all the changes you need, to make it work:

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/20rgfom5/5/)</kbd>**

**CSS:** Mentioned only the changes needed, rest remains same.

```
.sub-menu
{
    width:100%; 
    padding:0px;
}

.sub-menu li a
{
    padding:10px 28px 10px 10px;
}

.sub-menu ul
{
    position:absolute !important;
    width:100%;
    left:171px;
    top:0px;

}
```

Comment: Ooh this one helped a lot and the one I'm looking for! Thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I don't have a solution for you, but I can tell you what the problem is. All your sub-menus have an absolute position. - and you have the same "sub-menu" style on both a sub-menu and a sub-sub-menu.

If you want your sub--sub-menus to behave differently from a sub-menu, then I suggest you write a sub-sub-menu style.

They can both have the attributes common to both, but then have their own - eg positioning.

```
.sub-menu, .sub-sub-menu {
   width:160%;
   padding:5px 0px;
   position:absolute;
   top:100%;
   opacity:0;
   transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
   box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   background:#2e2728;
}
.sub-menu {
   left:0px;
   z-index:-1;
}
.sub-sub-menu
   left:50px;
   z-index:-1;
}
```

or whatever...

You also need to update all the styles inside the sub-menut hat have absolute positioning.

However - my advice is *not* to use absolute positioning if you don't need it.

Start be slowly removing "position:absolute; one at a time and see what changes... fix each change so it looks right... and keep removing it until you don't have any left to remove or until removing it can't be fixed.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me. The sub-menu is still below the Partial menu. :)

Comment: Yes I know it does not solve the problem - you then have to actually use proper left-positioning to move it to where you need it :) Which you would now actually be able to do for the menu (which you can't if they're all absolutely positioned over the top of each other)